How to listen for the cause of reactor netty triggering doOnError?
I located the problem and found that the Mono of webflux triggers doOnCancel. It seems to be caused by a browser link interruption, leading to the execution of doOnCancel. Now I want to know how to avoid my Mono from triggering doOnCancel due to upstream issues.
The following is my test code. When the browser page requests this interface and then immediately refreshes, it will trigger the execution of doOnCancel. However, I hope to avoid executing doOnCancel.
@GetMapping("/api/testOnCancel")
    public Mono<String> testOnCancel() {
        return Mono.just("1").
                flatMap(str -> Mono.just("test" + str))
                .delayElement(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
                .doOnCancel(() -> System.out.println("on cancel"))
                .doOnSuccess(str -> System.out.println("success"))
                .doOnError(System.out::println)
                .flatMap(str -> Mono.just("byby" + str));
    }


I have already solved this problem, and in order to help friends who encounter the same issue as me, I will answer it here.
Just add one cache operator call at the end.
@GetMapping("/api/testOnCancel")
    public Mono<String> testOnCancel() {
        return Mono.just("1").
                flatMap(str -> Mono.just("test" + str))
                .delayElement(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
                .doOnCancel(() -> System.out.println("on cancel"))
                .doOnSuccess(str -> System.out.println("success"))
                .doOnError(System.out::println)
                .flatMap(str -> Mono.just("byby" + str))
                .cache();
    }


cache() just stores the outcome of the first execution and immediately responds in the next ones. If it works for you, this means that the first execution was not cancelled, but the next ones were.
Just to visualise it, in my answer code example, if you do:
System.out.println(test.block());
System.out.println(test.block(Duration.ofSeconds(30)));
it will fail if you dont cache, after 2'30'' but it will succeed if you cache, after 2'1''

As you've already said, there is no cause of failure. This is why you don't see the cause in doOnError.
You've figured out that your mono is cancelled instead (probably because of the delay you add). You can find out some causes of cancel in this article on baeldung, like backpressure, insufficient resources etc.
Having this info in mind, your code is fine. It is handling cancellation by printing some message and if not cancelled but there is an error, you get to print it as well, so you see the cause.
Now, regarding the cancel event, you need to see why this happens. At some point you trigger a threshold that is lower than 2' and this cancels this mono execution (which should have no issues by default). To illustrate this, suppose we have a unit test:
@Test
void something() {
    Mono<String> test = Mono.just("1").
            flatMap(str -> Mono.just("test" + str))
            .delayElement(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
            .doOnCancel(() -> System.out.println("on cancel"))
            .doOnSuccess(str -> System.out.println("success"))
            .doOnError(System.out::println)
            .flatMap(str -> Mono.just("byby" + str));

    // uncommenting the next line should print 'success' + 'bybytest1' without errors, after 2m
    // System.out.println(test.block());
    // uncommenting next line should print 'on cancel' and a timeout error, after 30s:
    // java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 30000000000 NANOSECONDS
    // System.out.println(test.block(Duration.ofSeconds(30)));
}

